# How do I prevent switch-to-buffer-other-window from creating an unwanted new window?

Tags: window-splitting

I am seeing confusing behavior when using switch-to-buffer-other-window.

When there is only a single window, and I run these two commands:

M-x split-window-right

M-x other-window

M-x eval-expression "(switch-to-buffer-other-window (get-buffer "scratch.org"))"

Then there are only two windows open.

However, when there was only a single window, and I run these two commands:

M-x split-window-below

M-x other-window

M-x eval-expression "(switch-to-buffer-other-window (get-buffer "scratch.org"))"

Then emacs opens a third window and switches to the buffer in it.

Instead, I want emacs to switch to the buffer in the existing window above the one I am currently in. How to I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display-buffer` is the basic routine that decides how to display a buffer. It uses a variable `display-buffer-alist` to help it decide. You can modify that variable to use a different `action` than the default in order to do what you want. `C-h f display-buffer` gives you a list of action functions, e.g. here is the description of one of them: `‘display-buffer-use-least-recent-window’ -- Try to avoid re-using windows that have recently been switched to.` This looks promising, so we define a function that uses that as follows:

```el
(defun my/switch-to-buffer-other-window (buf)
  (let ((display-buffer-alist '((".*" display-buffer-use-least-recent-window))))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window buf)))
```

You can then use this function to switch to the buffer in the least-recently-used window:

```el
(my/switch-to-buffer-other-window (get-buffer "*scratch*"))
```

For (much more) information about `display-buffer`, consult [Displaying buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Buffers.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.

---

Keeping the functions separate allows you to use one or the other as the need arises. OTOH, if you want to permanently change the behavior, you could [advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) the original `switch-to-buffer-other-window` function to do the new thing:

```el
(defun use-least-recent-window (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let ((display-buffer-alist '((".*" display-buffer-use-least-recent-window))))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'switch-to-buffer-other-window :around #'use-least-recent-window)
```

If at any point you want to get rid of the advice, then evaluate the following:

```el
(advice-remove 'switch-to-buffer-other-window  #'use-least-recent-window)
```

---

Manipulating the heuristics used for window choice by `display-buffer` like this can be finicky. I believe there are higher-level libraries to do things like this conveniently, but I haven't used any of them and I cannot even remember names ATM, so I hope others will provide answers that use them. I am under the impression that they trade off flexibility for convenience, but you shouldn't put much stock in that.

EDIT: Here's one such library: [emacs-purpose](https://github.com/bmag/emacs-purpose/wiki) - but as I mentioned, I've never used it and I don't know much about it.